# Where does Kestrel look for what ports to listen to?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, kestrel-http-server

I have a couple of .NET Core apps, which when I run `dotnet run` decide to listen to different ports (one to 5000, one to both 5000 and 5001).

I've been looking around for some comprehensive documentation on exactly how these decisions are made, but can't find what I'm looking for.

What is an *exhaustive* list of places Kestrel looks for this setting, in order of precedence?

For simplicity, let's assume I'm using the default `WebHostBuilder`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: I'm _not_ looking for how to override this setting with a different choice. I know of several ways to do that (CLI args, env variables etc). I want to learn _all_ the ways this decision is made, to deepen my understanding.

Comment: The best place to check would be the source code on GitHub

Comment: @Nkosi: Yes, I've tried looking for it there, but I haven't learned my way around the code base (or even the org/repo structure for all the parts of .NET Core...) well enough yet to be able to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'll take a look when I get a chance. Show a simple example of the start up code you use for reference.

Comment: Some documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#endpoint-configuration

Comment: constants in source code https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/6fde01a825cffc09998d3f8a49464f7fbe40f9c4/src/Kestrel.Core/Internal/Infrastructure/Constants.cs

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation under [Endpoint configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#endpoint-configuration)

> By default, ASP.NET Core binds to:
>
> - `http://localhost:5000`
> - `https://localhost:5001` (when a local development certificate is present)
>
> **...**

The source code also supports this

```
/// <summary>
/// The endpoint Kestrel will bind to if nothing else is specified.
/// </summary>
public static readonly string DefaultServerAddress = "http://localhost:5000";

/// <summary>
/// The endpoint Kestrel will bind to if nothing else is specified and a default certificate is available.
/// </summary>
public static readonly string DefaultServerHttpsAddress = "https://localhost:5001";
```

Which is used by the internal [`AddressBinder`](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/6fde01a825cffc09998d3f8a49464f7fbe40f9c4/src/Kestrel.Core/Internal/AddressBinder.cs) to set the host and port to use by default when none is provided.

Comment: Nice, thanks! However, that only partially answers my question. I have a couple of api apps (services in a distributed application) with identical setup code like the one in the OP, but one listens to port 5000 and one to port 5001, both on HTTP. I'd like to understand why they're different.